# getting plugin com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon interrupted when open NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, dropbox, nsopenpanel, nsxpcconnection

I'm getting this messages on the console when I open a NSOpenPanel and then my application crashes:

```
plugin com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon interrupted
plugin com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon interrupted
Unable to setup extension context - error: Couldn't communicate with a helper application
```

And in the debugger I get an warning on the Thread 6 saying this:

```
Queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.apple-extension-service(serial)
    0_dispatch_barrier_async_f
12 start_wqthread
Enqueued from com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.apple-extension-service (Thread 6)
0_dispatch_barrier_async_f
```

I tried everything openning my NSOpenPannel with `[openPanel runModal]` and `[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:...`

I use NSOpenPanel just to open a txt file

What can I do to stop get this message and application stops crash?

The App is not sandboxed and code signed. I just trying only in the Debug-build because I don't have an apple developer account. The Mac OS X version is 10.10 and the dropbox version is 3.0.3

Comment: Please add following Information to the question to find the cause of crash: Is you App sandboxed (influenced XPC)? Is your App code signed (influences OpenPanel)? Is it only in the DEBUG-Build? Do you open/run the Panel from main-thread? Which OS-Version? Which version of DropBox?

Comment: We (Dropbox) would be happy to take a look at this. Can you please open a ticket at https://www.dropbox.com/support , then copy me your ticket ID (found at https://dropbox.zendesk.com )? I'll route it to the right people. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg Any update on getting this solved? Happens in Xcode for me too.

Comment: I don't believe we ever heard from the original developer here and so weren't able to sort this out. Please feel free to open a ticket yourself and copy me the ticket ID and I'll get this to the right people. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg I too am seeing this bug as well now. Did this person ever open up that bug? I'd be happy to myself if need be.

Comment: I don't believe we ever heard back on this. Please do open one and reply here with the ticket ID. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still having this problem with "Dropbox Finder Integration"

Comment: @Greg I am suffering from it, and it blocks the OSX app(debug version) to use presentViewControllerAsSheet. I have no idea what's the relation between them.. but it happened.

Comment: I can't help with this myself, but if you (or anyone else) are still having trouble with this @Adison, please open a ticket and post the ID so I can get it to the right people. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So I had the same problem while working with Python. I think its a problem with the Finder integration of Dropbox in Yosemite. I am guessing you are using Finder (for selecting files, etc.) in your application.

**Disabling the Finder-Dropbox** integration worked for me:

1. Go to Dropbox icon > Cog wheel at the bottom left > Preferences
2. Disable "Enable Finder Integration"

I don't know if there is a proper way to solve this as of yet, but this workaround seems to work.

My versions: Dropbox 3.0.3, Yosemite 10.90

*Reference: [applehelpwriter.com - How to remove Dropbox green blobs](http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/10/24/how-to-remove-dropbox-green-blobs/)*

Comment: I had the same problem in R 3.2.1 GUI 1.66 Mavericks build (6956)

Comment: This isn't a good way to solve the problem because I'm not going to do that process to use the app for every user I have

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error: "plugin com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon invalidated" when using NSOpen panel from Swift "in house" program; not sandboxed not code-signed.

OS X: El Capitan: 10.11.4 (15E65)
Dropbox: Reporting "up to date" as of today (9 April 2016)

Disabling Finder integration helped getting rid of messages.

Comment: Disabling Dropbox Finder integration for me isn't a good way to solve the problem because for every user I have, I'm not going to tell him to disable his Dropbox Finder integration to use the app properly